# Why can't property observers be added to lazy properties?

Tags: ios, swift

I watched a tutorial on swift basics and a passing comment was made that property observers can't be added to lazy properties, but no reason was given. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3):

The docs do confirm this:

> You can add property observers to any stored properties you define, apart from lazy stored properties
>
> [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

but they do not provide a rationale.

I would guess that property observers must access the property they are observing to attach itself as an observer although it does not 'feel' like you are. Again, this is just a guess, but if I am correct, then obviously having a lazy property is irrelevant. Lazy properties are computed when first accessed and if using an observer accesses that property then it would be computed immediately, which completely defeats the purpose of it in the first place.

Comment: The property observer mechanism in Swift is entirely separate and different from KVO observing.

Comment: @zneak, yes, I thought I made that clear, I'll remove that example to eliminate any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 5.3 now you can use lazy property observer. It make us possible to declaring property without assign any default value. (https://www.swiftbysundell.com/tips/lazy-property-observers/)

```
lazy var totalSteps: Int = 0{
    willSet(newTotalSteps) {
        print("About to set totalSteps to \(newTotalSteps)")
    }
    didSet {
        if totalSteps > oldValue  {
            print("Added \(totalSteps - oldValue) steps")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final class A {
    init() {
        print("!")
    }
}

final class B {
    lazy var a = A()
}

B().a = A()
```

You will get only one "!" as output here. My guess is that allowing `didSet` here will make this situation much more complicated.